# How to scroll through a list sent by ajax in python?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have this code where you sent via ajax a list with the found values ​​of the class .title

my.js

```
$('#quoterform').validate({
       submitHandler: function (form) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var lista = [];
           $('.title').each(function () {
               lista.push($(this).text());
           });

           $.ajax({
               url: '/payment/',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                   csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                   'lista[]': JSON.stringify(lista),
               },
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (response_data) {
               }
            });
           form.submit();
       }
});
```

What I need is that when I receive this information in views.py scroll through the list that is sent by ajax and then send it to payment.html

That's what I have in views.py

views.py

```
def payment(request):
    print ("Entro a payment")
    print request.POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pagos = []
        if request.POST.get("lista[]") != '':
                datos = Survey(titulo="")
                pagos.append(datos)
        return render_to_response("payment.html", {'pagos': pagos},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        response_data = {}
        response_data['response'] = "ok"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

payment.html

```
{% for datos in pagos %}
<div class="rsm-pym">
     <p class="letter">{{ datos.titulo }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: what's the value of `request.POST.get("lista[]")` in `views.py` ?

Comment: As far as I can see you code does exactly what you're asking about. If the list is not showing in payment.html maybe the error is in the template instead of the view

Comment: The value displayed is "None"

Comment: @yorodm The template shows the values ​​that I put to the Survey () but what I want is to collect the array that was already sent and show all the values ​​it contains.

Comment: What happens if you use `getlist` instead of `get`?

Comment: @LuisOrduz Show this [u'["<Value of the class .title >"]']

Comment: I just copied this exact code and create a form and used the same class and it's working for me using `getlist`, are you sure `.title` is the appropriate selector? Could you include the form?

Comment: Yes `.title` is the selector I need.